# Time triggered Azure function - Bearer token generation to call a protected API

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-functions, microsoft-identity-platform

I am trying to write an Azure function which is time triggered and runs every 10 minutes.

The function needs to call an API which expects a bearer token.

How do I generate the token? Since it is time based, I can't have a user to login and give function authorization token by signing into MS Identity platform which can be used to get the access token.

Comment: Hi Arshad, may I know if the answer is what you expect ? If it doesn't match your requirement, please let me know. I will try to help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to get the token by the code below in your timer trigger function:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "client_id", "<your app client id>" },
    { "scope", "<scope>" },
    { "username", "<your user name>" },
    { "password", "<your password>" },
    { "grant_type", "password" },
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

var response = await client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);

var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Then you need to parse `responseString`(in json type) and use the access token in it to request your api.

**Update:**

[Get token by client credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "client_id", "<your app client id>" },
    { "scope", "<scope>" },
    { "client_secret", "<your app client secret>" },
    { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

var response = await client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);

var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you. Using password grant is one option but I thinking if there is a way to do it without using password grant. It is not allowed for us to use password grant.

Comment: Hi @ArshadAli Do you mind use client credential grant ? If it can match your requriement, please refer to the "Update" in my answer. You can set the sensitive information such as password and client secret in azure key vault regardless of using password grant or client credential grant.

Comment: I tried the client credential grant but the problem is I need to generate token with user context, a service account.

Comment: Hi @ArshadAli I'm afraid we can not get the access token with user context if we don't use password grant. If we don't use password grant, we may get token with user context, but it needs interaction actions which may be difficult in azure function timer trigger.

Comment: Yeah. I thought so. Thank you. I have created another http triggered azure function to let user generate it once and then persisting the refresh token for this time trigger function to use and update for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a password grant flow but this requires you to provide user and password to your application. A better approach is to do the Auth outside of your application using device code flow.

See this repo for an example:

https://github.com/blueboxes/devicecodesample